# is it possible that my intel video driver is malfunctioning?

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, intel, steam

So, I've installed Steam on an Acer laptop aspire V5-131 which has a duo-core processor (model: 1017U) and 8 gb on RAM with Xubuntu 14.10. and installed some games, particularly hotline miami, and been getting excelent FPS.

Recently my old laptop came back from the technician and installed and tried to play the same game. The computer I'm refering to is a Toshiba Satellite E205 with and i5 processor (model i5-430M, and  Mobile Intel HM57 Express Chipset and Mobile Intel HD Graphics with 64MB-1696MB dynamically allocated shared graphics memory and also 8 gb of RAM with Ubuntu 15.04) and the refered game performs terribly getting even as low as 20 FPS, aside from the gaming issue sometimes playing HD video looks choppy.

I've tried downloading the Intel Linux graphics installer from  [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) in an xubuntu 14.10 installation in the same machine not getting any better luck. so my concrete question is if there's a chance that the default packaged driver is malfunctioning?....and if so, could there be a workaround to get the right one?.

In advance Thank you so much. I know it sound like a duplicated question but I haven't found any other post that mentions steam. THANKS